# React Native/iOS: App hangs at splash screen after it is opened from a push notification

Tags: ios, react-native

I am buiding a RN app with [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) and [react-native-bootsplash](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash).

**The issue**

-I implemented push notification functionality, and when I open the app from push notification, the app hangs at splash screen forever without transitioning to the main app.

-The app also doesn't crash, so I guess the app is functioning---just that for some reason the splash screen isn't going away.

-When I open the app from pressing the app icon, the splash screen goes away as expected, so this is related to push notification.

-For Android, there is such issue, so this issue is iOS-specific.

Assuming that there is nothing wrong with the packages themselves:

-What might be a root cause of this?

-What should I check/investigate to tackle this issue?

Here is my AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RNFBMessagingModule.h"
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import "RNBootSplash.h"


#if DEBUG
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
    FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
    SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
    [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
    [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
    [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
    [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
    [client start];
    }
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    #if DEBUG
        InitializeFlipper(application);
    #endif
    [FIRApp configure];
    NSDictionary *appProperties = [RNFBMessagingModule addCustomPropsToUserProps:nil withLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

    RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
    RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"MyApp" initialProperties:appProperties];
    rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
    rootViewController.view = rootView;
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [RNBootSplash initWithStoryboard:@"BootSplash" rootView:rootView];

    return YES;

}

-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge {
    #ifdef DEBUG
        return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
    #else
        return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
    #endif
}


@end
```

I know this is a high-level question, so some kind of high-level guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd try and remove RNBootSplash from the equation so that you can see if anything else is going on. Can you temporarily comment it out and try to open the app?

Comment: @scgough, thanks for the suggestion. I commented out everything RNBootSplash from AppDelegate.m and also from App.js, but the issue persists--now the app remains at a black screen forever. At this point I am just scratching my head...any idea on where it is coming from? :(